# How to get the currently activated venv?

Tags: python, sh, python-venv

I created a python virtual environment using `venv`. and then I activated it. so how do I know the path of and the name of the venv I created? I am sure there is a way cause, zsh is showing me the activated environment name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stored in the environment variable `VIRTUAL_ENV`:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ python -m venv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ echo $VIRTUAL_ENV 
/tmp/venv
```